# What is the attribute_id for tier_price used for in the catalog_product_entity_decimal table?

Tags: magento2.2, sql

In the Magento 2.2.9 database, what is the 'tier_price' attribute used for in the 'catalog_product_entity_decimal' table? This seems to give some kind of error while trying to save new product tier_prices.

My database has entries with the attribute_id of the tier price entry here but tier_price values are stored in the 'catalog_product_entity_tier_price' table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clear the data from the 'catalog_product_entity_decimal' table with the attribute_id of tier_price (92 for me), then you are able to save new tier_prices for products.

Magento 2.2.9 does as far as i know nothing with tier_price attribute values in the 'catalog_product_entity_decimal' table.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is 92.

```
*************************** 74. row ***************************
 attribute_id: 92
 entity_type_id: 4
 attribute_code: tier_price
 attribute_model: NULL
 backend_model: Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Tierprice
 backend_type: decimal
 backend_table: NULL
 frontend_model: NULL
 frontend_input: text
 frontend_label: Tier Price
 frontend_class: NULL
 source_model: NULL
 is_required: 0
 is_user_defined: 0
 default_value: NULL
 is_unique: 0
 note: NULL
```